# Unity, Moving Ball Along a Path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spline

Alright, I've tried asking over at Unity and on Reddit and got nothing, hopefully I can get some help here!

I'm trying to move a ball along a circular path. The thing is, I don't want it to be automatic or even constant, I want the user to be able to tap the ball and then it will move around on the path coming to a stop until the user taps on it again. Essentially, I want to take this cat toy and turn it into a mobile game.

http://g03.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1i0U3MXXXXXbRXFXXq6xXFXXXR/Three-Layers-Funny-Intelligence-Cat-Toy-Amusement-Ball-Tower-Of-Tracks-Removable-Non-Slip-Plastic-Pet.jpg_640x640.jpg

I've got all my objects in the scene, I'm using a bezier spline in order to make the path, all I have to do is find a way to add force to the balls along the path. Please help me out guys I really want to get this done!

Comment: you just use one of the many available SPLINE packages.  look for spline pro or mega-shapes (and that company's related produdts).  it's inconceivable you would program this from scratch, one's self.  no more than you would program from scratch, say, game physics, an email client, or a mysql database.  it is man-years of work to do this. just grab one of the existing packages and learn how to use it.

Comment: That's fine, but how do I know that the package I'm paying for will do what I want. I don't want to pay for one of these packages just to have it not do what I'm looking for. This doesn't seem like it is too complicated a thing to do, I just don't know the code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a cheat-y way, and you would have to find some sort of way to 'animate' the ball rolling if needs be.

But if the spline is a uniform circle you could achieve the same effect by parenting the ball to an empty game object at the centre of where the spline is currently and performing a quaternion rotation on the empty object on tapping the ball.

Comment: Okay, I looked that up and again, it seems like a way to make an object automatically spin around an axis. I have no problem  making an object do that. I just can't make it to where the user applies force to the ball making it follow a spline.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [Hermite Spline Controller](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Hermite_Spline_Controller) plugin from Unity website. It is free and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbEYRb14bms) is a video for setting it up. The video is much more better and easier to understand than written how to set it up here.

Comment: just as Programmer says, there are even free assets for this.

Comment: Okay, that really just helps me move the ball along the spline automatically. I've already found a way to do that. What I am looking for is a way to actually have the user push the ball around the spline by tapping on it. Essentially each tap is going to push the ball along the spline with the objective being to keep the ball in motion for as long as possible.